# apache2 multuple(too many) ruby processes

Tags: ruby, apache2, passenger

[image]

The screenshot above is `top` output on my server. The server is responding very slow. I have apache-passenger setup. The output shows 13 processes from apache user (`www-data`) and I could not identify the reason behind these many ruby processes. Can any one please point me in the correct direction ??
Thanks...

Comment: I have also tried `PassengerMaxPoolSize 2`
`PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 2` but still same output..

Comment: As I can see your system uses a lot of swap.  Consider disabling unnecessary apache modules or replacing apache with nginx in order to save some RAM.